# Компиляция в формат apk кода с форматом .py и .kv

Tags: python, компиляция, kivy

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, которая связана с компиляцией кода в формат `apk`.

Я попытался скомпилировать в `buildozer` два файла с кодами, один из которых содержал формат `py` а другой `kv` У меня скомпилировался только файл в формате `py` и при запуске на `android` у меня ничего не высвечивается, т.к. все гаджеты в файле `kv` Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне добавить в файл `apk` файл с расширением `kv`? Вот код из файла с расширением `py`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
class Widgets(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widgets, self).__init__()
 
    def btn_clk1(self):
        self.labe.text="ouu"
    def btn_clk2(self):
        self.lbl.text="ser"
class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Widgets()
SimpleKivy().run()
```

А вот код из файла с расширением `kv`:

```
<Widgets>:
    lbl: my_label
    labe: my_labels
    Button:
        size: 100,75
        pos: 0,0
        text: "1"
        color: 0,1,0,1
        font_size: 40
        on_press: root.btn_clk1()
    Button:
        id: 1
        size: 170,75
        pos: 100,0
        text: "2"
        color: 1,0,0,1
        font_size: 40
        on_press: root.btn_clk2()
    TextInput:
        id: my_label
        size: 300,300
        pos: 300,0
        text: ""
        color: 1,0,0,1
        font_size: 40
    TextInput:
        id: my_labels
        size: 300,300
        pos: 300,300
        text: ""
        color: 1,0,0,1
        font_size: 40
```

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно!
В файле `buildozer.spec` укажите в переменной  `source.include_exts` расширения файлов, которые должны присутствовать в конечной сборке аpk!

Совет: загляните сюда -  https://habrahabr.ru/users/HeaTTheatR/topics/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).